# Google Colab reports error: "ValueError: None.json is not exists!"

Tags: python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook

`git clone https://github.com/ososos888/prune-then-distill.git`

This is GitHub repository I am trying to run the code from few days in Google Colab.

`python prune-then-distill/main.py --pre_train`

This is command I'm trying to run but I'm facing some error. They are:

```
File "/content/prune-then-distill/main.py", line 7, in \<module\>
platform = Platform()
File "/content/prune-then-distill/utils/platforms.py", line 15, in __init__
self.start_setup(mode)
File "/content/prune-then-distill/utils/platforms.py", line 119, in start_setup
self.hparam_setup()
File "/content/prune-then-distill/utils/platforms.py", line 221, in hparam_setup
raise ValueError(f"{self.opt.hparam_fname}.json is not exists!")
ValueError: None.json is not exists!
```

In Google Colab I have CPU connection and also CUDA installation.

The code where i am getting error

```
class Platform:
    def __init__(self, mode=None, logger_type=None):
        self.opt = self.get_parser()
        self.start_setup(mode)
        self.model_path = self.get_model_path()
        make_dir(self.model_path["result_path"])
        self.device = set_cuda(self.opt.GPU_num)
        self.logger = Logger(self.opt, self.model_path["result_path"], mode, logger_type)

        # Save hyperparameter to .json file
        with open(f"{self.model_path['result_path']}/hyperparameter.json", "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(vars(self.opt), json_file, indent=4)

def hparam_setup(self):
        """
        This function is automatically determines the stored hyperparameter according to the set opt.model_type.
        """
        # Get file path
        param_folder_path = "experiments/hyperparam"
        param_fpath = []

        if self.opt.hparam_fname is None:
            if self.opt.pre_train is True:
                param_fpath.append("train_default")
            if self.opt.pruning is True:
                param_fpath.append("prune_default")
            if self.opt.kd is True:
                param_fpath.append("kd_default")
        else:
            param_fpath = self.opt.hparam_fname

        for index, path in enumerate(param_fpath):
            path = os.path.join(param_folder_path, f"{path}.json")
            param_fpath[index] = path

        # Check file exists
        for path in param_fpath:
            if os.path.exists(path) is False:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.opt.hparam_fname}.json is not exists!")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.  Apparently ```self.opt.hparam_fname``` is not defined (i.e. ```None```)  Why? No idea.  How does ```self.opt.hparam_fname``` get setup?

Comment: Even I am not getting what exact that  code means  .I took this  code from github repository for my project prine then distill . I  share that link the above in the question

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works.  You present your code as a minimal reproducible example.  Not as a link, as links tend to come and go for some reasons or another.  You need to include your code as text.

Comment: '''class Platform:
    def __init__(self, mode=None, logger_type=None):
        self.opt = self.get_parser()
        self.start_setup(mode)
        self.model_path = self.get_model_path()
        make_dir(self.model_path["result_path"])
        self.device = set_cuda(self.opt.GPU_num)
        self.logger = Logger(self.opt, self.model_path["result_path"], mode, logger_type)'''

Comment: this is code for the first error which i m getting .i m not able to put whole code in commet because its too big that why i m putting the code by dividing it inti small part

Comment: def start_setup(self, mode):
        """
        Set the basic settings according to the general experiment mode and test (unittest) mode.
        INPUT:
            mode(:obj:`str`):
                Variable for setting mode. Receives `None` or test(`str` when unittest) value as input.
            logger_type(:obj:`str`):
                Variable for setting mode. Receives `None` or an arbitrary `str` value as input.
        """

Comment: if mode is None:
            self.hparam_setup()
            self.set_seed()
        elif mode == 'test':
            self.opt.result_fname = "unittest"
        else:
            raise ValueError("Please check mode option value")
        if self.opt.experiment_name is None:
            self.opt.experiment_name = self.get_result_path_name()

Comment: i divide my code where i am getting error into three part and posted here plzz help me

Comment: # Check file exists
        for path in param_fpath:
            if os.path.exists(path) is False:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.opt.hparam_fname}.json is not exists!")

Comment: Please.  Don't put your code in the comments.  Always include additional code in your original post.

Comment: sorry, I am new to the stackoverflow  so I dont know exactly how to use it or how to edit code n all send it in question, I will try and upload the question as well as code in proper way